# How do I back up my Motorola Droid?

Tags: motorola-droid, backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to backup an Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/390/how-to-backup-an-android-device)

Hi,

I have a Motorola Droid that I need to send in for repair. How can I back up everything to my PC easily?

The Moto Phone Portal expects you to individually download each photo. I would rather not transfer everything through wifi to my PC or to the cloud.

- Photos
- Contacts - gmail
- App settings?
- Playlists ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your contact -Gmail are already saved in GMail isn't it ?

And Photo, playlists are on the SD card, so just keep it / change it / backup it with a card reader

For app settings, some of them are on sd card, and if you use [app2sd](http://android.a0soft.com/), all your apps are on the sd card

For your SMS, you can use [SMS Backup +](http://www.appbrain.com/app/sms-backup/com.zegoggles.smssync) to back it up on GMail:

[image: QR - Backup +]

If you have a rooted phone, you can use [Titanium Backup ★ root](http://www.appbrain.com/app/titanium-backup-%E2%98%85-root/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup):

[image: QR - Titanium Backup ★ root]

Good luck!