# Locale app & export settings

Tags: backup, locale

Is there any solution to backup Locale settings? I've defined couple of rules and I don't want to lose them while I reinstall some custom ROM.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to backup an Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/390/how-to-backup-an-android-device)

Comment: The first answer to that question mentions Titanium Backup, which (if you're rooted) can be used to back up individual apps.  I'll add an answer for non-root.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. While backing up the whole device would, in effect do what Hubidubi wants, exporting the settings from the app could be used for more than just backup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from the Locale's [feedback forum](http://feedback.twofortyfouram.com/forums/5655-locale-feedback/suggestions/74784-backup-settings) regarding the Backup/Restore functionality:

> AUTOMATIC BACKUP/RESTORE
>   Locale has
>   automatic backup and restore using
>   Android 2.2's cloud-based backup
>   mechanism. There are no configuration
>   options within Locale--it just works!
>
> To use this feature, simply make sure
>   that backup/restore is enabled by
>   going to the Android Settings ->
>   Privacy and verifying that the
>   checkboxes for Backup and Restore are
>   both checked. Whenever Locale is
>   uninstalled and reinstalled, the
>   device is factory reset, or you
>   upgrade to a new device, the
>   situations will be automatically
>   restored as long as Android is set up
>   with the same Google account.
>
> Locale's backup and restore is
>   designed to work correctly across
>   different devices with different
>   hardware and software capabilities.
>   For example, let's say a backup was
>   made on a device with Wi-Fi and
>   restored to a device without Wi-Fi.
>   Locale will properly handle that
>   transition.
>
> Automatic backup and restore requires
>   Android 2.2 or later, as well as a
>   handset supporting Google's backup
>   manager. If there are no options for
>   Backup and Restore under Android
>   Settings -> Privacy, then the device
>   does not support backup and restore.
>
> Since backups are tried to a Google
>   account, be sure to always use the
>   same Google account when setting up
>   your Android devices.
>
> MANUAL BACKUP/RESTORE
>   In addition,
>   there is a beta manual backup/restore
>   feature to create a manual backup to
>   the SD card. This feature is disabled
>   by default, and must be manually
>   enabled. After backups are enabled, a
>   new Backup menu item will appear under
>   the menu of the Locale home screen.
>   From that menu item, you can create a
>   backup to the phone's SD card. When
>   Locale is re-installed, it will
>   automatically detect any existing
>   backups and ask whether you'd like to
>   restore them. Because manual backups
>   are a beta feature, we are unable to
>   offer any support. To enable manual
>   backups, please follow these
>   instructions:
>
> 1. Allow installing apps outside of the Android Market
>      a. Go to the Android Settings
>      b. Tap on Applications
>      c. Tap on Unknown sources
> 2. Install Backup Enabler
>      a. Open the web browser on your phone
>      b. Go to this address: www.twofortyfouram.com/backup.apk
>      c. Once the download completes, tap on the download
>      d. Follow the instructions to install
> 3. Perform backup
>      a. Open Locale
>      b. Choose Menu -> Backup