# Transfer applications and settings from my old Android phone to my new one

Tags: backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to backup an Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/390/how-to-backup-an-android-device)

I recently purchased a new Android device and I would like to be able to back up all of my settings/installed applications/app settings so that I can easily transfer them from the old phone to the new phone.

I know that my Gmail synced items will automatically sync, but this doesn't help me with things like bookmarks and settings on my apps.

Are there any good applications available on the market for helping me with this transfer?

I'm not sure if it will cause any problems, but the old device is running Android 1.6, and the new device will be running Android 2.x

Answer (score 4):

Titanuim Backup, MyBackup, Astro FileManager, Handy Backup and there are loads more in the market!