# Create Defy Kernel Backup

Tags: backup, kernel, motorola-defy

I own a Motorola Defy and it is running 2.2.2. 
I was wondering if i could create a backup of my kernel by any means!

Is there any software/application/method which can help me achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Please see this previous "How to backup an Android device?" question http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/390/how-to-backup-an-android-device

Answer (score 1):

As GAThrawn already indicated, the answer to your question is covered by [How to backup an Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/390/how-to-backup-an-android-device). As far as the kernel is concerned, two of the answers apply:

- using `adb pull` to do a file system copy as described [in this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/9528/16575)
- create a Nandroid Backup from within your custom recovery as detailled [in this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/20303/16575)

Both variants require your device to be rooted, and for the Nandroid backup you will need to have a custom recovery (e.g. ClockworkMod) installed.