# Best custom rom for i9100?

Tags: rooting

I want to upgrade my s2 to lollipop but before that I want to backup my stock rom so that if in future I can reinstall it. Even tell me about best method of rooting I9100 and from where I can download lollipop for i9100. Currently I am running jellybean 4.1.2 version on my s2.
You can also suggest me any other good ROM.

Comment: i banned from edit posts but, just search with this Tag = `backup`.and : http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20296/how-do-i-back-up-and-restore-my-phone-before-installing-a-custom-rom

Comment: The second portion of your question (which you've now put in your title) is not really suitable for our site either. It would fall under "Questions asking us to **find or recommend an app, device, ROM, accessory or off-site resource** are off-topic for Android Enthusiasts as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam and become obsolete quickly." Alternatively, it would be considered a duplicate of [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/981)