# backing up apps for firmware upgrade

Tags: backup, restore, sony-xperia-z2

I really don't want to have to re-install all apps and sign into them after I upgrade firmware. Is there a way to back them up? Any tips that may ease the process are appreciated (I have my photos/videos backed up through google and a lot of apps do sync after I sign into them). The main problem is typing in all the passwords for the various apps is going to be a pain.

Is there a way I can export a list of all the installed apps and automatically download them again?

Comment: Did you try these questions: [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices), [How do I back up (and restore) my phone before installing a custom ROM?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20296/how-do-i-back-up-and-restore-my-phone-before-installing-a-custom-rom), [How to backup an Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/390/how-to-backup-an-android-device).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Titanium Backup PRO Key ★ root(available in the Google Play Store, by developer "Titanium Track") is the easiest way to back up your apps exactly as they are. The pay version ($5.99) should be pretty close to what you're looking for, [Titanium Backup PRO Key ★ root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackupPro&hl=en).

Comment: Thanks, I gave it a look but could you say more as to how you actually use it?