# How do I back up my phone?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to backup an Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/390/how-to-backup-an-android-device)

I need to offload all my info from phone to laptop.  I've enabled mass storage and plugged my phone in via USB to do this but it will not let me transfer the info. What do I need to do?

Comment: What kind of info are you trying to back up specifically?

Comment: What error you get when you are trying to backup your SD on laptop?

Comment: Are you rooted?

Comment: Not sure if this is ICS specific, but there is an option to "Back up my data" (to Google servers) in Settings > Backup & reset.

Answer (score 3):

The best application I've found for this is [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en). It will save copies of your applications and all their associated data.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you get a copy of Samsung Kies with your Galaxy? If you did - it has options to backup some of the phone data, but it won't backup everything (ie no apps for reinstallation).