# How to save an ISO (or similar) of a whole Lexibook tablet (Android SO)?

Tags: applications, backup, system-apps, backup-manager

A friend has 2 Lexibook android tablets (kids' tablets). One is completely clean and the other is fine.

He wants his clean android to be exactly the same as his good one.

How does he copy?

I got the tablet's in my hands and the main problem until now is I can't even download nandroid. Is there anyway I can?

Please note: he is looking to have a complete copy, not just data and not just software.

Comment: ...and [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/20303/16575) to that question. Yupp, agreed.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I got the tablets in my hand now and the "faulty" is actually empty and I weren't able to get the backup done yet because I can't download the nandroid so I am unable to proceed with the instructions received in the answers you pointed me too.

Comment: This Lexibook is a children's tablet and is a real pain. I deactivated all protections in the settings but how can I download the nandroid tool to backup the system?

Comment: Tat "Nandroid tool" is part of custom recoveries. Details can be found via our [nandroid tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/nandroid/info). Besides, such a transfer only works between identical devices; never restore a Nandroid backup from a different device, as that is very likely to cause a "brick". Carefully read all related information before you proceed.

Comment: The device being a Lexibook it created many problems to many parents as I could see online. We gave up on those devices. Thank you for your advice @Izzy.