# I need to do a factory reset on my phone

Tags: backup, factory-reset

I need to do a factory reset of my phone. I have the Alcatel one touch fierce 2
How and where do I back up my apps and data.

Comment: Margaret: First welcome to Android Enthusiasts! You've already found our `backup` tag. On our site, most tags have a tag-wiki with first aid and information if you hover your mouse over them and select the "info" link. You might wish to see our [backup tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info), which gives you all details you need, e.g. pointing to [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/16575) / [How to backup an Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/390/16575) and other places, plus giving details on different methods.

Answer (score 0):

**Back Up Applications:**

- Tap "Apps" while on the home screen.
- Tap "Settings" and go to "Backup and reset".
- You need to be logged in to your Google account to back up your apps, so if necessary tap "Backup account" > "Add account" and follow the on-screen prompts to sign in with, or create a new Google account.
- Mark the "Back up my data" check box.

**Restoring Apps:**

- Tap "Apps" from the home screen.
- Tap "Settings" and go to "Backup and reset".
- Sign in to the Google account you've used for backing up the apps. To do so, tap "Backup account" > "Add account" and follow the on-screen instructions.
- Mark the "Automatic restore" check box.

**Backing Up Contacts:**

- Tap "Apps" from the home screen.
- Tap "Settings" and select the account to sync.
- Mark the "Contacts" check box.
- Press "Menu" and tap "Sync now".

**NOTE: Contacts will automatically be restored the next time you sign in with your Google account.**

**Backing Up Media Files:**

- Open the apps drawer and launch the "Photos" app.
- Press "Menu" and tap "Settings".
- Tap "Auto Backup".
- Tap the "Auto Backup" switch and set it to "ON".
- You need to be logged in to a Google account, so if necessary, tap "Backup account" > "Add account" and follow the on-screen instructions to log in or create a Google backup account.
- Set the "Backup Storage" preferences as you desire.
  Set the "Backup Settings" preferences.
- To learn more about backing up media files using this method, tap "About Auto Backup".

**NOTE: Media files will be restored automatically after you sign in with the Google account used for the backup.**

**Alternatively, as Firelord correctly pointed out, you can use the [Helium](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup&hl=en) app or a MTP connection to back up your apps and data.**

**Factory Reset:**

- From the home screen, tap "Apps".
- Swipe to "Personal" and tap "Backup & reset".
- Scroll to "Personal Data" and tap "Factory data reset".
- Tap "Reset phone" > "Erase everything".

**[Source](http://cellphoneforums.net/general-cell-phone-forum/t376152-alcatel-onetouch-fierce-2-back-up-restore-data.html#axzz3DkogBZkK)**

Comment: Google Backup as you've described won't cover all apps data: apps must explicitly support that, and only few do. Neither would I fully trust the contacts/calendar sync as only way – plus not everybody wants to have his/her data on those servers.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for bringing that to my attention. I'll make the required changes as soon as I get to a desktop...

Comment: While on it: *Contacts › Menu › Export/Import › Export to SD Card* (and lateron of course *Import from SD Card*) gives a local backup, no cloud required.

Answer (score 0):

[Super Backup](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.idea.backup.smscontacts%26hl%3Den&ei=pWz2VLlYgumYBeHEgfgN&usg=AFQjCNEY_5pVor08Z1fvteXy3QhZNf9Oag&sig2=14FmL9Xx2FNwIc_XAXIxHw&bvm=bv.87519884,d.dGY) can backup your apps, contacts, calendars, messages and call logs. If your phone is rooted, it can also backup your apps' data.

In terms of data, just plug your phone into your computer and copy paste everything you need.