# Android Backup manager - restore from Nougat to Marshmallow

Tags: adb, 6.0-marshmallow, backup, restore, 7.0-nougat

**Earlier Device:** LG Nexus 5X.
**My Device:** OnePlus 3

Earlier, I was able to use Tap&Go or just import all the data by signing into my Google Acc.
However, with my device, when I used Tap&Go or Google account sign-in (tried few hard resets), I was not able to choose my earlier device 
get data from. Only my old Galaxy Nexus was shown.
This resulted in phone not being setup, apps not being automatically installed or have the data restored...
I had to install apps manually however my data was not restored.

As it always worked well, I guess the issue might be with my earlier device running a newer version of android than my device (Nougat vs Marshmallow).   Or that some services are missing?

Anyone got into the same situation and can help?

I have tried restoring using `adb bmgr`, but it resulted in device not visible as well. Nexus 5x sees all 3 devices while OP3 sees just the 2.

```
shell@OnePlus3:/ $ bmgr list sets

33dbec2b8d69e175 : ONEPLUS A3003

3bcd9da5b052e84e : Galaxy Nexus
```

---

```
bullhead:/ $ bmgr list sets

34d36f59351444be : PiTRiS - Nexus 5x

33dbec2b8d69e175 : ONEPLUS A3003

3bcd9da5b052e84e : Galaxy Nexus
```

Any chance this is an issue with nougat, that it can't restore to Marshmallow? Or any other way how to force restore from 5X?
Thanks

Comment: I agree with your guess. You can't restore a backup of an app to an older version of the app, and of course all the system apps (including the package manager) are an older version in Marshmallow.

Comment: This is not the issue, I'd understand that. Issue is, that Nougat device is not visible at all in Marshmallow. And I have a lot of apps, that are same version on M as on N. Guess it's more of a system issue, that backup format is incompatible and therefore not showing up.

Comment: Tried backing up the app I need using "adb backup", but in this particular case, it ended up with really small backup, which is uselss (no data). Found at, it's really similar to backing up for example temple run - http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1986927 - data is stored somewhere where adb backup cannot reach. In ext storage in android/data, there are just cache files. Seems lost, I'll have to wait for A7 update for OP3 and then restore needed app from cloud.

Answer (score 0):

For reference: One way is to use Titanium Backup app on older phone and then just restore the app's data on newer phone after transferring the backup data. The same thing could be accomplished using adb from your home computer, but you'd have to backup each app's data separately.

see this thread for more:
[How to backup an Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/390/how-to-backup-an-android-device)