# How to back up & restore a rooted phone?

Tags: root-access, backup, magisk

Before handing in my OnePlus 6T for repair, I want to create a full system backup and reset the phone to factory defaults. Afterwards, I want to restore the original state. My phone is rooted with Magisk.

*How do I do a full system backup?*

Note that this is different from a backup as part of migration to a new phone or a partial backup as part of fixing software issues.

Comment: what do you mean with full **system** backup? and what do you mean with restore **original** state? usually just **data** backup is required. *adb backup* does not fulfill the needs, look for other tools like *Titanium* or *Migrate* or use *adb pull* to get a disk image. for full system backup use TWRP recovery (be aware Internal Storage is not included in TWRP backup)

Comment: What I mean by *full system backup* is a backup that I can use to restore the device to the exact same state as it was before I did a factory reset. So all applications on all screens should still work as before, all the photos should still be there, etc. Note that I do additional individual backups of data. However, in order not to waste a lot of time for restore, I just want to do a full backup and restore. I tried [OnePlus Switch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oneplus.backuprestore&hl=en). That restored applications, but not their settings. It was not of much help.

Comment: @alecxs Note that I don't need to use `adb`. I was just showing what I tried. If TWRP is the better tool, then - with a bit of details - that would be a good answer.

Comment: There exist a number of similar questions. See [backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info), [titanium-backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titanium-backup) and [twrp](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btwrp%5D+backup) tags. Also [how to backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=how%20to%20backup). From TWRP official site: [What should I back up in TWRP?](https://twrp.me/faq/whattobackup.html) and [What is EXCLUDED from a TWRP backup?](https://twrp.me/faq/backupexclusions.html)

Comment: factory reset does only format userdata partition, therefore no system backup needed. be aware when restoring userdata backup,  issues for which you wanted to reset will be restored back, too. for TWRP [Migrate](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3862763) is recommended for selection what apps to restore

Comment: @alecxs As I wrote, I want to backup for handing in the phone for repair. Softwarewise it is fine. I clarified that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: *This method will not work with work profiles or parallel apps!*

Here's how I performed the backup on a OnePlus 6T in 2020:

1. Downloaded [TWRP](https://twrp.me/Devices/) for my device.
2. Rebooted the phone into *fastboot mode* by pressing volume down
   plus the power button and following the menu displayed on the
   phone. Note the process of entering fastboot mode varies from
   phone to phone.
3. Connected the phone to the PC, then booted TWRP from the Windows
   command line (`cmd.exe`):

   ```
   fastboot boot twrp-3.4.0-0-fajita.img
   ```

   I installed `fastboot` as part of the Chocolatey package [adb](https://chocolatey.org/packages/adb).
4. In TWRP, I entered my password, then selected *Backup*.
5. Backed up all partitions to internal storage. See also the TWRP
   FAQ: [What should I back up in TWRP?](https://twrp.me/faq/whattobackup.html)

   Note that not all partitions need to be backed up, and in fact,
   according to the TWRP FAQ, it may be a bad idea to restore certain
   partitions. Still, it doesn’t hurt to have the backup of all of
   them.

   Not included is `/data/media` (internal storage). This needs to be
   backed up separately. See the TWRP FAQ: [What is EXCLUDED from a
   TWRP backup?](https://twrp.me/faq/backupexclusions.html)
6. With TWRP running, I connected the phone via USB to my PC. Then I
   moved the following folder to my PC, which contains the TWRP
   backup of the phone:

   ```
   This PC\OnePlus A6013\Internal Storage\TWRP
   ```

   This step is not strictly necessary as in the following step I
   did back up the entire internal storage. However, it makes the
   next step execute faster as less data needs to be copied. The next
   step does not give feedback about progress.
7. For backing up internal storage I decided on the method found in
   Tadej Janež’s article [Backing up Android's /data/media (i.e.
   internal storage) using adb and TWRP](https://tadej.ja.nez.si/android-internal-storage-backup.html). From the Windows command
   line I ran:

   ```
   adb exec-out "tar --create data/media/0 2>/errors.txt | gzip" >internal_storage.tar.gz
   ```

   After completion, to check for errors, I ran (no errors):

   ```
   adb shell cat /errors.txt
   ```
8. To leave TWRP, I rebooted the phone. Note that it is *not*
   necessary to install TWRP.

Restoration still needs to be tested.